# Adding Spring Security to Gradle project breaks Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to add Spring Security to my project but upon adding it to my gradle file and importing the changes, suddenly the Spring Data JPA dependency is no longer functional.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-repository-jpa')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

The error I get:

> Warning:***root project 'x': Unable to resolve
>   additional project configuration.** Details:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compile'. Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not
>   find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-repository-jpa:.
>   Required by:
>       project :*

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

No such thing `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-repository-jpa` exists.

It should be `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

Comment: Strange, cause application was working fine with that. Now that I've changed it, I get "Java: cannot find symbol" errors.

Comment: I cannot find `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-repository-jpa` in the spring repositories. Even a Google search brings nothing. I would check the Local History if you are using IntelliJ to see how it was working before. There is double quotes around security dependency, but it is no problem. Works fine in my IDE.